# What's the difference between takeown and Set-Acl for changing ownership?

Tags: powershell, permissions, file-permissions, ownership

Suppose I want to take ownership by setting the owner to `Builtin\Administrators` of some folders on a NAS. I can do this in two ways:

**Using CMD**

```
takeown /F "\\Server\Share\My Folder" /A
```

**Using Powershell**

```
$ACL = Get-Acl -Path "\\Server\Share\My Folder"
$Account = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Builtin\Administrators")
$ACL.SetOwner($Account)
Set-Acl -Path "\\Server\Share\My Folder" -AclObject $ACL
```

Since MS wants to move everyone to Powershell I would assume that the Powershell way is preferred, but I vaguely remember seeing a situation where `Set-Acl` did not work but `takeown` did. Is there functionally a difference between these two ways and if so, which is the recommended method?

EDIT: if this question is better suited for StackOverflow I can move it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do effectively the same thing, but here's one difference you might be remembering. `takeown /F file.txt` technically only requires the "Take Ownership" NTFS file permission, and does not necessarily need to be elevated via UAC prompt to take ownership of a file with your current user.

Changing the owner via `Set-Acl`, `icacls`, or the file security gui requires `SeRestorePrivilege` (elevation), because they are able to pick a different user as the owner. Granting owner permissions to a different user/group like `Builtin\Administrators`  **requires** elevation, so `takeown /A` will behave identically to the other commands anyways in almost every case.

`takeown` will also choke out on long path names like many cmd tools, but powershell can use extended-length paths like `Get-Acl -LiteralPath \\?\C:\folder\file.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I've used Lee Holmes' article on how to elevate privileges in the same instance, so I guess that using this would mean that as long as the PWSH instance is elevated, I can grant myself the SeRestorePrivilege and Set-Acl should work just as well then :) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Set-Acl is a powershell command, and takeown is a Command Prompt command.

Command prompt commands also works in powershell, but their output is not structured to easily work with powershell.

Given you are using powershell, set-acl would be the preferred method to use.

Set-Acl should always work, but might require you to run powershell as administrator first. The same applies for takeown though.